# jquery mobile is ruining my POST

Tags: php, jquery-mobile, post

I have a HTML file (index.html) containing a HEAD section and a BODY section. In the BODy section I have a form with a POST action pointing to a php file.

If I add to the HEAD section the CDN of jQueryMobile... then the POST stops working. How is this possible, and how to avoid this?

So my Head looks like this:

```
<head>
    <title>My Mobile App</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1 maximum-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/icon57.png" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="images/icon72.png" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="images/icon114.png" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="images/icon320.png" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" sizes="768x1004" href="images/icon320.png" />
</head>

** if I comment the jquery.mobile script line the POST works **
```

And the BODY with the POST looks like this:

```
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="index">
                <header data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
                    <h1>Mobile APP</h1>
                </header>
                <div data-role="content">
                    <b>Login</b>
                    <form method="POST" action="prologin.php">
                        Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
                        Password: <input type="password" name="pass"><br>
                        <input type="submit" value="Login" data-inline="true" data-icon="gear">
                    </form>
                </div>

                <footer data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
                    <h1>bla bla</h1>
                </footer>
    </div>
</body>
```

Now my PHP file prologin.php is more complicated but for debugging purposes I reduced it to:

```
<?php
echo 'name='.$_POST['name'].' and pass='.$_POST['pass'];
?>
```

So, when I use the jQuery.mobile scripts, the result of clicking the Login button is an undefined page where if I view the page source... It's empty, I mean it looks like :

```
name= and pass=
```

, so nothing was POSTED
If I comment the script line with jQuery.mobile, the result shows what it should, I mean:

```
name=myusername and pass=mypassword
```

(of course myusername and mypassword are the values I enter in the input boxes)
What am I doing wrong?

This same pages and code worked just fine on another server. But now it does not work anymore. What could be wrong? The original host was also a CENTOS system, same configuration mostly. On the working server I had PHP Version 5.3.3 and on this one (not working) I have PHP Version 5.1.6 
How can using jquery mobile affect the HTML POST in such way that it would stop working?

I mean, how can i fix it?

I would try to update my PHP but on this server there are other apps that rely on this version and I would avoid updating.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add this attribute to your form:

```
data-ajax="false"
```

It will prevent jQuery Mobile from hijacking form submit logic.

Your form should look like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="prologin.php" data-ajax="false">
```

Comment: Thank you. I did not know this. And it solved my problem. Although it's bizarre how this problem only occurs on one server and does not on another.

Comment: Just a note... inexplicable again... now it works without data-ajax="false" in FORM. I think there was a problem in my php syntax for current_date. I mean I was not using date() but a newer version of the same function. I do not understand this anymore :( It is inexplicable because it did not work with the simplified php that only echoed the POST.

Answer (score 0):

You could Add data-ajax="false" to your form tag but that shuts off most of the cool features of using jquery mobile in the first place.

The solution I came up with to overcome this same problem was to use the 'pagebeforechange' event to look at the request being made and change any get requests to a post request using the built in 'changePage' method.

Here is an example of what I am doing.  It's important to note that all of this code is placed in the head section BEFORE you load the jquery mobile library!

EDIT:
I removed unrelated portions of code from the project I am using this in and it may have gotten broken in the process.  You can get an un-edited version of the code that works just fine here, but you will have to edit out all the extraneous items that are unrelated:

[function load_mobile_resources()](http://pastebin.com/qAc0VCEK)

I call the above function in the head section of every mobile page like so:

```
 <?php
 load_modile_resources();
 ?>
```

The reduced and possibly broken code is below:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {



        // =============================================
        // ALL PAGES
        // =============================================

        // -- pagebeforechange --
        $(document).on( "pagebeforechange", function( event, data ){
            if ( typeof data.toPage === "string" ) {                    
                // intercept a page change request
                // can alter any aspect of this request, if needed                  

                if ('options' in data) {
                    if ('type' in data.options && data.options.type == 'post') {
                        //console.log('type is already post -- NOT converting get to post (it probably just was)');
                    }else{
                        // intercept this get request and make it a post request with the avsession value injected

                        // This is an example of how you can exclude certain pages or paths from the get to post conversion
                        if(! (data.toPage.indexOf('resources/') == -1) ){
                            //console.log('this is a resources request -- NOT converting get to post');

                        // Don't want to mess with the built in popup feature
                        }else if('role' in data.options && data.options.role == 'popup'){
                            //console.log('this is a popup -- NOT converting get to post');

                        // Don't want to mess with the built in handling after a popup is closed
                        }else if(data.options.changeHash == false && data.options.fromHashChange == true){
                            //console.log('this is a popup being closed (or browser fwd/back) -- NOT converting get to post');

                        }else{
                            // -- ok we want to mess with this one ...
                            // -- stop the current process
                            // console.log('converting get request to a post');
                            event.preventDefault();
                            convert_get_to_post(data.toPage, false);
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        });

    }); // end function


    function convert_get_to_post(urlStr, forceReload){
        postData = new Object;
        var urlObj = $.mobile.path.parseUrl(urlStr);

        // Note:  I commented out, but didn't totally remove, examples of how you can ensure
        //        that certain data is always passed around.  Int his case it was a session
        //        key called avsession

        if(urlObj.search){
            // -- ensure any query string parameters are sent as post data
            var dataStr = urlObj.search.toString();
            dataStr = dataStr.replace(/^\?/,'');
            dataPairs = dataStr.split('&');
            //console.log('here is the dataPairs');
            //console.log(dataPairs);
            //var avsessionFound=0;
            for (x in dataPairs) {
                dataPair = dataPairs[x];
                //console.log(dataPair);
                var dataSet = dataPair.split('=');
                //console.log('here is the dataSet');
                //console.log(dataSet);
                postData[dataSet[0]]=dataSet[1];
                //if(dataSet[0]=='avsession'){
                //  avsessionFound=1;
                    //console.log('avsession found: '+dataSet[1]);
                //}
            }
            //if(avsessionFound==0){
                // inject the avsession value into the post data
                //postData['avsession'] = $.jStorage.get('avsession', '');
            //}
            //console.log('here is the postData');
            //console.log(postData);

            // send this request as a post
            $.mobile.changePage(urlObj.hrefNoSearch, {data: postData, type: 'post', reloadPage: forceReload});

        }else{
            // no query string to worry about jsut send this as a post with the avsession value injected
            //postData['avsession'] = $.jStorage.get('avsession', '');
            $.mobile.changePage(urlObj.hrefNoSearch, {data: postData, type: 'post'});
        }

    }
</script>
```

Comment: I did like you said, but it does not work. setting data-ajax to false works. I do not know yet the implications and side-effects of using this data-ajax solution but it's the only one that works

Comment: I hacked out a bunch of other stuff related to the project I am using it in so perhaps I broke something in the process of doing that.  To anyone who uses this code, I would suggest UN-commenting all console.log stuff so you can see what is going on.  It took me a few days to get everything working exactly the way I needed it to.

Comment: Edited answer to include original un-edited code that is working in my projects.